# App engine channel successfully created but unusable

Tags: google-app-engine, channel-api

I have been getting an intermittent problem using the App Engine channel API. For the most, maybe 90% of the time, everything works fine. But the remaining 10% of the time I get a channel that is unusable. Having looked at this code for months, I strongly believe that this problem is not due to a logical error. By unusable channel I mean that even though the client connects to it successfully, the server is not able to message it. Most of the operations involved on the client and server complete successfully:

- On the server, I create a channel with a new client id unique to the session
- The client fetches the corresponding token and connects to it
- On the client, onOpen() is called on the channel socket

The one thing that doesn't succeed is the calling of /_ah/channel/connected for these defective channels. I've tried dozens of possible workarounds without success. Right now I deal with the problem by gracefully retrying till I succeed, but it would be really nice for it to work without these tricks.

Answer (score 1):

I havent seen any code but from what you are saying could it be related to

[Intermittent error code 400, description “” on client connecting to channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13962739/intermittent-error-code-400-description-on-client-connecting-to-channel?rq=1)

I am using a kind of brute force loop messaging to all client sockets (even if they have been closed, its a bit redundant but the overhead seems low ) and haven't picked up any problems yet (I also havent tested it that well either)

Comment: Heh, I posted that question too - it's related, but a different problem based on my tests. In that problem you get an error so you can at least do something about it, even though at present nothing seems to guarantee resolution. In this case, there's no error - you get a channel that looks valid, all calls succeed but is actually dead. Also - the other problem seems to occur more frequently than this one.

Comment: If you want to post some code snippets I can run it here and try and replicate your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that they fixed a leak in the channels APi in the last release 1.8.2: https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9283
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/wiki/SdkForJavaReleaseNotes

Comment: Thanks, everyone using channels should update to 1.8.2 then. Though this point has nothing to do with the question :-)